# Google Drive API does not work when trying to query files in My Drive, no exception thrown, just empty list while my drives actually contains files

Tags: google-drive-api

Was trying to use Google Drive API (Java) in my android project. I logged in successfully, and was able to use the list() method successfully, but the getFiles() method return a empty List whereas my google drive actually having more than 100 files. I couldn't find any answer regarding this.

Comment: BTW I used OAuth 2 for credential

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example] so that i can test your code.